# During linux bootup smartd daemon turns itself off because "No devices to monitor"

Tags: linux, boot, opensuse

opensuse leap 15.4 on asus l210 laptop

```
/media/q/HDD1 $ systemctl status smartd.service
× smartd.service - Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smartd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-11-26 16:35:54 PST; 1min 28s ago
       Docs: man:smartd(8)
             man:smartd.conf(5)
    Process: 892 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smartd -n $smartd_opts (code=exited, status=17)
   Main PID: 892 (code=exited, status=17)
     Status: "No devices to monitor"
lines 1-8/8 (END)
```

In /etc/smartd.conf I changed the line

```
DEVICESCAN
to
DEVICESCAN -d removable
```

because I have an sd[x] device that I sometimes use, and sometimes not.

man smartd.conf states about type -d

```
    removable - the device or its media is removable. This indicates
to smartd that it should continue (instead of exiting, which is the
default behavior) if the device does not appear to be present when
smartd is started.
```

Regardless, the smartd daemon still exits during bootup. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it doesn't matter if smartd exits at this point, because when the fs system is mounted the smart daemon is restarted, and then performs its check, if scheduled.
That is, issuing the command

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

after it has been mounted, declares the check to have been performed.